# Display the information from a SQLite Query in the browser

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi

So, I'm trying to use PHP in order to query an sqlite database, I have no problem with the connection or with the query itself, however, I don't know what I could do in order to display the data in a clean way, or even put it inside an HTML table. The code I'm working with right now is:

```
<?PHP
    $connection = new SQLite3('my_db.db');
    if($connection){
        echo "Connected\n";
    }
    $results = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM Meter1');
    while($row=$results->fetchArray()){
        var_dump($row);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have done a `$row = fetchArray()` the variable `$row` is a array containing the data returned from your query in the form of an Array. If you add `SQLITE3_ASSOC` it will be an Associative Array where the keys are the names of the database columns.

So lets assume your table has the columns `id, name, dob` then this would be how you get to that column data

```
<?php
    $connection = new SQLite3('my_db.db');
    if($connection){
        echo "Connected\n";
    }
    $results = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM Meter1');
    while($row=$results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        echo 'id = ' . $row['id'] . '<br>';
        echo 'name = ' . $row['name'] . '<br>';
        echo 'Date of Birth = ' . $row['dob'] . '<br>';

    }
?>
```

So if you want the data in a table its just a case of wrapping the HTML around that while loop like this

```
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>Date of Birth</td></tr>';
    while($row=$results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[dob]</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```